# splats in array literals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.9

according to the latest article by Dave Thomas in the pragpub magazine http://pragprog.com/magazines Ruby 1.9 should accept multiple splat arguments in array literals, *eg*:

```
[ *'2'..'10', *%w{ J Q K A } ]
```

But on my machine I am getting a parsing failure. Under 1.9.1p378, i am only getting the last array literal returned and under 1.9.2p0 I am getting a parse error reading the comma between literals.

```
ruby-1.9.1-p378 :001 > [ *'2'..'10', *%w{ J Q K A } ]
 => ["J", "Q", "K", "A"] 


ruby-1.9.2-p0 > [ *'2'..'10', *%w{ J Q K A } ]
SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):13: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ']'
```

update: my ruby settings:

```
  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.2p0"
    date:         "2010-08-18"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin10.4.0"
    patchlevel:   "2010-08-18 revision 29036"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]"
```

I'm curious if anyone else is getting this syntax to work?

Comment: Can you splat a `Range` like that, without converting it to an `Array`?  edit: turns out you can, even in 1.8.  Damn cool!

Comment: WorksForMePerfectly with 1.9.2p0 (Win 7 x64)

Comment: Also worked fine in 1.9.1p243

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fetched head for 1.9.2 and recompiled, below are my settings:

```
  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.2p94"
    date:         "2010-12-08"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin10.5.0"
    patchlevel:   "2010-12-08 revision 30140"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p94 (2010-12-08 revision 30140) [x86_64-darwin10.5.0]"
```

so apparently it was fixed by the time @Beerlington compiled and seems fixed on ruby edge.

```
ruby-1.9.2-head :001 > [ *'2'..'10', *%w{ J Q K A } ]
 => ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
```

Comment: 1.9.2 is intended to replace all installations of 1.9.1, as it's the first "production ready" version.

Comment: yah, the weird thing is that I was using 1.9.2p0 and it wasn't working, but I think that there must have been an incompatibility perhaps in the last os x upgrade which was fixed by recompiling ruby after the update. I dunno, its the best guess i can muster.

Comment: If you installed 1.9.2-p0, then installed Snow Leopard, you'd have to recompile Ruby. Leopard was 32-bit and Snow Leopard is 64-bit. You'll also need to recompile all your gems with native code as they will now be upset. I think `gem pristine --all` will do it.

Comment: @greg, no it was compiled under snow leopard (note the ruby version above indicates x86-64) but before the latest snow leopard 10.5.6 upgrade.

Comment: hmmm. I didn't have to do any recompilation after the last update. Now you've got me wondering if I should. :-) Naw, "if it ain't broke, don't fix it." :-)